# fluent api - Mapear tabela para outra tabela com mesma chave

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Preciso saber como mapear no fluent API o seguinte item

```
public class ImportacaoHeader
{
    public string IdImportacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataInicio { get; set; }
 }

public class ImportacaoLog
{
    public string IdImportacao { get; set; }
    public string CodigoCampo { get; set; }
}
```

O problema é o seguinte, IdImportacao na tabela ImportacaoHeader é chave e IdImportacao tb é chave em importacaoLog, Sendo que para cada importacaoheader eu tenho varias ocorrências em ImportacaoLog e o relaciomento entre as duas tabelas é o mesmo campo chave nas duas, antes de mais nada já aviso que não posso alterar as tabelas elas já existem senão já teria feito e resolvido, 
como posso mapear isso no fluent api, como ficaria a sintaxe, e o que eu teria de alterar nas classes acima?

Comment: Se o campo `IdImportacao` na tabela `ImportacaoLog` é chave **primária**, é impossível ter várias ocorrências para um mesmo `ImportacaoHeader`. Ou ela é uma **Foreign Key** (logo ela teria algum outro campo sendo chave primária), ou é uma chave primária composta, nesse caso a chave primária poderia ser composta pelo `IdImportacao` e pelo `CodigoCampo`, ou seja, poderia ter várias ocorrências para um mesmo `ImportacaoHeader`, mas somente um para cada `CodigoCampo`. Qual das duas situações é a tua?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja o exemplo de como você pode fazer.

```
public class ImportacaoHeader
{
    public string IdImportacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataInicio { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ImportacaoLog> Importacao { get; set; }
}

public class ImportacaoLog
{
    public string IdImportacao { get; set; }
    public string CodigoCampo { get; set; }
    public ImportacaoHeader ImportacaoHeader { get; set; }
}

public class SeuContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ImportacaoLog> ImportacaoLog { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GrImportacaoHeaderade> ImportacaoHeader { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // configures one-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<ImportacaoLog>()
            .HasRequired<ImportacaoHeader>(s => s.ImportacaoHeader)
            .WithMany(g => g.ImportacaoLog)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("IdImportacao "));  // Use o id da FK identica ao que esta no banco        
    }    
}
```

Veja como mapear os campos com o mesmo nome que esta no banco [aqui](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx).

Exemplo;

Nome da tabela;

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ImportacaoLog>().ToTable("XXXYYYZZZ"); // XXXYYYZZZ Nome que esta no banco
```

propriedades;

```
//Configure Column
        modelBuilder.Entity<ImportacaoLog>()
                    .Property(p => p.DateAnivesario)
                    .HasColumnName("DT_Anive") // DT_Anive o que esta no banco
                    .HasColumnOrder(3)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");
```

[Referencia 1](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

[Referencia 2](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx)

Comment: Então consegui resolver vou postar aqui depois